# How to filter deeply stacked data inside an object(and edit\delete it afterwards)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a problem here, and I can't find out how to solve it. I have an object with many levels. There is arrays with objects inside my object, and they have their arrays with objects too. Let me show you somekind of example here:

```
{
  sections: [
    {
      currency_sections: [
        {
          positions: [
            {
              id: 131,
              quantity: 24
            },
            {
              id: 133,
              quantity: 1       
            }
          ],
          key: value,
          key: value
        },
        {
          positions: [
            {
              id: 136,
              quantity: 2
            },
            {
              id: 137,
              quantity: 3       
            }
          ],
          key: value,
          key: value
        }      
      ],
      key: value,
      key: value
    }
  ],
  key: value,
  key: value
}
```

I build my data via handlebars template. Which is not really important. But on my page I can change, let's say, quantity of the position. When I do that I have only id of the position I changed and new quantity.

So basically I need to filter my object to find one object in positions arrays that matches via id key and change quantity there.

Also I can delete whole position, and in that case I need to find position object with id needed and delete whole object.

The thing I can't understand is how I can filter all my data at once. And how can I manipulate unnamed object if I will find it.

And let's say I filtered it somehow. Can I return full path to that object for later use? In example - sections[0].currency_sections[1].positions[0] ? Because if I can do that than deleting and editing should be simple enough.

At this point I don't really have the time to redo everything on something more suitable like angular or ember. Although I have underscore and jquery.

Comment: How about iterating through the object once, and building a new object which maps `positionID -> [parentArray, index]`. In addition to simplifying deletion, it may also be faster than filtering the object multiple times.

Comment: not a bad idea, although I need to make multiple indexes, since there is at least 3 parent arrays

Comment: you dont. You can store an actual reference to the parentArray. When you do `var a = someArray`, `a` contains a pointer to the array referenced by  `someArray`.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? Lets say I did iteration to build index.. each => each => each and builded new object with positionId: [parentArray, index]; Now I need to manipulate that data via key. So I have my original object where I need to change data. So I need to kinda filter it via my stored index with parentAttay pointer or something?

Comment: This should help clarify - http://jsfiddle.net/saskwr1c/

Comment: @UtherTG I worked on this problem last year. This post might help you. You'll just need to tweak the code a bit: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57976/deep-pick-using-lodash-underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update my question. At the end I just created a method that builds index of my elements.

```
function _createItemsIndex(data) {
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    $.each(data.sections, function (sectionIndex, section) {
      $.each(section.currency_sections, function (curSecIndex, curSec) {
        $.each(curSec.positions, function (positionIndex, position) {
          _items.push({
            id: position.id,
            quantity: position.quantity,
            price: parseFloat(position.price) || 0,
            index: [sectionIndex, curSecIndex, positionIndex]
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Thank you levi for your comments